# Infinite product calculation

Tags: infinite-product

I want to calculate

$ \displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1- {{c_i}\over a}) $
where $\displaystyle lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} c_i=0$ and $a$ is a small positive constant

Is the information I provided enough? It must converge to zero.

I can't seem to find the euler products of any use. I also tried to prove that the power series$  \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1-{{c_i}\over a}) $ converges to $-\infty$.

Comment: If the product has to converge to 0, the series has to converge to $-\infty$. However the information $ \lim c_i=0$ is not sufficient

Comment: $\lim_ic_i=0$ is a necessary condition for convergence. But it is not enough. You can't expect to get a value without knowing $c_i'$s.

Comment: @guestDiego thanks for the correction I edited my question .

Comment: And thanks to both for the fast answers, I will check again and be back

Comment: The constant $a$ is unnecessary, you should absorb it in the $C_i$'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Taylor,

$$\log(1-c_i)\approx-c_i-\frac{c_i^2}2-\cdots.$$

So if $c_i=\Omega\left(\frac1n\right)$, the series goes to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Notice that since $e^x \geq 1 + x$ for any real $x$, you can bound $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 - \frac{c_i}{a}) \le \prod_{i=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{c_i}{a}} = \exp[-1/a \sum_{i\geq 1} c_i]$.